# Room matching in Message admin/relocate comes up with stupid suggestions

Tags: bug, chat

We have some *peculiarities* in [SO's C++ room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/10/loungec), one of which is that we move offending messages to the [bin](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/549/bin), rather than annoying all of the 10k+ users across the whole chat with flags. (We have many owners, so that almost always at least one of them is present and can do that.)

Now, every time I do that, I am surprised about what rooms the damn feature suggests when I type "bin" into the room search box:

[image: rooms suggested for "bin"]

**How in the world can "Android People" or "Casual chat" be a better match for "bin" than, erm,** ***"bin"?***

Please note: I *know* very well that this allows for a lot of great jokes, but please believe me when I say that, after a year or two of laughing at them, those jokes aren't all that great anymore, and this becomes quite tedious. At least I am long since past the stage where I enjoy making those, I just have to ask for the real reason.

Comment: Even the choice to favorite a room to bring it to the top would be okay for now, I'd imagine.

Comment: Android People and Casual Chat both have "bin" in their description, so it seems to weight title and description matches evenly and then (presumably) orders the results by recent activity. I don't know why those choices were made, though.

Comment: (as a side note) If you actually search for "bin" with quotation marks it seems to reduce the number of results on the normal room list at least, but the order is probably still not guaranteed to be consistent.

Comment: @Tim: I would, however, expect the room's _name_ to play a more important role in finding a room than the room's _description_. Especially, when the prompt read _"Enter the room_ ___name___ _to search for the target room."_ And the need to quote the name to find by name is meh.

Comment: Not to mention that what you put in is an exact match for the room name. I agree on both points.